# Access xml file from groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I need a code example of groovy script which can access a xml file stored anywhere in my file system .
In this xml file i have the database credentials , my script need to access the database .
below is the xml

```
<jdbc-datasource>
    <url>dbURL</url>
    <driver-class>jdbcDriver</driver-class>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</jdbc-datasource>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the file is at: `/home/mizan/db.xml`

Then this should do it:

```
def dbxml = new File( '/home/mizan/db.xml' ).withReader {
  new XmlSlurper().parse( it )
}

// Check it has worked...
assert dbxml.'driver-class' == 'jdbcDriver'
```

Comment: Thanks Tim ,I need to read the values in the tags <url> ,<username>,<password> . How to do that ?

Comment: `def (url,user,pass) = [ dbxml.url, dbxml.username, dbxml.password ]` should do it?

Comment: I need to get the values , i need these to access the database , I cannot specify this in the code . I tried your way but it is not working , I get blank value .